# Galaxy editor use unit type for trigger?

Tags: starcraft-2, galaxy-editor

I have a trigger using the event Unit Enters/Leaves Range of Unit, but it seems to want a specific unit. For the sake of brevity (and saving time for me), how do i set the trigger to find a unit that enters range of any of a specific type of unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to use a trigger for this? It sounds like the functionality you're looking for would work much better as an aura-like ability.

I've been fiddling with my SC2MapEditor -- I don't think there's a simple way to implement the ability with that event, as it's designed to work with a single unit. You might could try something with unitgroups, but even that returns only one (rather than all) of the units in the unitgroup.

It might also help if you informed us what you were trying to do.

Comment: I'm designing a map where instead of gathering resources directly, you control beacons which give you resources. Abilities might work, investigating...

Comment: I meant informed us what you wanted the ability to do. Change ownership?

Comment: What i basically want my unit to do is to change ownership then provide mineral production for the player that owns the unit, and also perhaps provide things like defensive buffs to the owning player's units.

Comment: Ok, i've rigged a system that will work for my needs except for 1 part: i need to make my units research an upgrade on command instead of being user-triggered. Is this possible? Edit: looks like that's doable. Now working on disabling a behavior on command.

Comment: All right, after mucking with abilities for several hours last night, i gave up on that for now. I have a couple of trigger-related ideas that I want to try, then if those dont work i'll post on a mapping site (www.sc2mapster.com) to see if someone there can help me.

Comment: @RCIX -- starcraft 2 map editor questions are within the scope of Gamedev.stackexchange also -- perhaps you should try there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have been messing around in the editor and have done something similar to what you are trying to do. I found the best way to do this is to take a sensor tower and change nothing but the effect, its rather easy to change the effect to give out a certain number of minerals per minute etc.